# iphone 4S 6.0.1 has poor wifi reception upstairs

Tags: wifi, iphone

I've had an iphone 4S running 6.0.1 for just about a month. I find that it has trouble connecting to wifi when I'm in my room upstairs.  It connects fine downstairs (which is where the combo. router/modem resides.) I tried a Macbook to test the connection in my room and it had a very strong wifi connection.
What can I do?  The wifi seems to work well in other situations, including at work, which is in a hospital, so I'm sure I'm not near a modem/router.

Comment: I have found iPhone to have less signal reception strength then a Macbook. Perhaps you could get a signal booster.

Comment: perhaps it is a software problem, this is the case with my iphone 4s. upgarde>>>

Answer (score 2):

WiFi networks require two-way communication.  Even though your *router* may have enough strength to send a signal to that room, whatever wireless client *device* you want to use in that room **also** has to have enough strength to send a signal *back* to the router.

Evidently, the Macbook you tested in the room had enough strength to send a decent signal back to the router.  Yet, the iPhone did not.  Signal effectiveness is a combination of a number of variables, two being antenna configuration, and power.  Your iPhone's WiFi antenna and/or power are inferior to the computer's.

What you could do is either **move the wireless router closer to (or into) the room**, or else **set up another access point to extend your network's wireless reach**.

To get a new access point talking to your existing network's router, you'll need to consider using wireless-to-wireless repeating, power line network adapters, or an Ethernet cable – Ethernet being the best option, if you can somehow run a cable from point A to point B.